# DAX measure with TOTALMTD running slow

Tags: performance, dax

I have two measures in my tabular cube.

The first one called

```
'Number of Days' := CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(SUMMARIZE('A'[Date])))
```

The second one will includes the first one as its expression

```
'Number of Days (MTD)' := CALCULATE(TOTALMTD([Number of Days],'A'[Date]))
```

The second measure when I browse the cube and pull out the measure.
It runs incredibly slow.

Any idea how I can optimize these measurements and make it run faster?

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyrEf.png)

`Volume:= SUMX(A, DIVIDE([Volume],2))`

`Volume (MTD):= TOTALMTD([Volume],'A'[Date])`

**Updated extra measurements**

Comment: Is `'A'` a Calendar/Date table? Note **TOTALMTD** is a Time Intelligence function which only works properly with a table marked as Date/Calendar. I think you can use explicit filters but you will have to provide data sample in order to help you.

Comment: Hi alejandro, the 'A' is a fact table which contains a date column called 'Date'.
I have uploaded the 'Sample Data' - the first column will be showing the original 'A'[Date] data; the second column is the first measurement i mentioned above; the third column will be the second measurement i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice should be creating a Calendar/Date table and use TOTALMTD Time Intelligence function. However this approach can be used if your model doesn't include a Date table.

First measure, number of days:

```
Num of Days := DISTINCTCOUNT(A[Date])
```

Cumulative measure:

```
Num of days (MTD) :=
CALCULATE (
    [Num of Days],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( A ),
        [Date] <= MAX ( A[Date] )
            && MONTH ( [Date] ) = MONTH ( MAX ( [Date] ) )
            && YEAR ( [Date] ) = YEAR ( MAX ( [Date] ) )
    )
)
```

**UPDATE:** Added screenshot.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** It seems you need to calculate a cumulative total, in that case just use the below expression for the second measure:

```
Num of days (MTD) :=
CALCULATE ( [Num of Days], FILTER ( ALL ( A ), [Date] <= MAX ( A[Date] ) ) )
```

**UPDATE 3:** Usuing SUMX and DISTINCT to count distinct dates.

Replace the first measure by the following:

```
Num of Days = SUMX(DISTINCT(A[Date]), 1)
```

> This solution could be more performant than use COUNTROWS + SUMMARIZE,
> however it could be very slow depending on the number of rows and the
> machine where it is running.

Comment: I will try on this alejandro.
No matter this helps or not, thanks for your efforts.
Will come back to you later.

Comment: Hi @alejandro,
The result returned with the your measure seems incorrect compared to mine. 
Basically, yours expression will accumulate from starting to end.
But what I want is just accumulate month by month.

Let's say if January i only have 10/1, 11/1, 12/1 - I will get 1, 2, 3 for the Num of days (MTD) measure and February i have 3/2 and 4/2 - it will recalculate starts from 1, and the result i get will be 1,2.

Comment: @KingsleyTan, I've updated my answer with a matrix in Power BI (It should work in PowerPivot too), using the created measures. Is not it your expected result?

Comment: I've uploaded my screenshot too. Just wondering why it looks different to yours. Do you have any idea? I created the measures with exactly the same expression as you stated above.

Comment: @KingsleyTan, please edit your question to include the screenshot not my answer. It seems you need to perform a running value against the distinct count.

Comment: sorry about that. I am still new to stackoverflow. It was my mistake just now, your expression looks fine and returned expected result. But it still takes quite long time, around 71 sec. Is it normal? @alejandro

Comment: @KingsleyTan, It depends on a bunch of things, your server, configuration of your Tabular Instance, number of rows, etc. One thing you can do is try to calculate it from the source.

Comment: number of rows is definitely an issue here, because the data is from one of my huge table, it is like 3xxxxxxx. I got another measure to count the MTD values too, but that one looks much faster with SUM function as the base measurement. Maybe I can share you the other measurement expression up there. @alejandro

Comment: Therefore, I am curious is it the base measurement DISTINCTCOUNT function causing the slow performance issue. @alejandro

Comment: @KingsleyTan, I think you can also create a column or calculated column that allows you filter the rows that must be comulative count through months and mark them with `1` then you just can use SUM.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it? or any reference? Just started to learn DAX not long ago... Would appreciate if you able to help on this. @alejandro

Comment: @KingsleyTan, Does the 'A' table have repeated date values? Please explain what do you need to calculate with the second measure, what I can interpret from your DAX is that you need to count the number of unique dates values through months. is that right?

Comment: Yes, 'A' table do have repeated dates, that is why i did the distinct count on the base measurement. That is exactly what i want! @alejandro

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @alejandro I have marked your answer, the sumx distinct definitely improved the performance a lots.